# Specific Search for Projects

Tags: git, github

Mastering a new tool or technology I constantly suffer from lack of example projects — the open source projects which I could use as a base for practical studies.

Unfortunately, searching at Github I cannot be more precise other than a project's language. For example, I can't specify that I need a project written in Ruby, with Sinatra as a back-end, Backbone as a front-end, and Cucumber and RSpec as the BDD tools.

So, until the Github team add tags to their splendid service, how can I better solve the aforementioned problem?

Comment: Maybe belongs to [webapps.se]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, **Samy**. Yes, it helped me. However, I'd like to be more specific searching for projects. As it turned out, there is a service called [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/). It allows you to search for open source projects and moreover you can browse the projects by one or more [tags](http://www.ohloh.net/tags) which undoubtedly is a very useful feature for my purposes described above. Unfortunatelly, using Ohloh you can't search for all projects hosted at Github and the Ohloh own project database is very, very small. So, the question is still open.

Answer (score 2):

I usually *play* with Google search to find what I want.

For example:

- `"app.rb" "spec" site:github.com` to search for Sinatra projects using RSpec. This example won't work if Sinatra's main file isn't called *app.rb*.
- `"describe" "last_response.body" "should change" site:github.com` to look for a specific test code.

I don't know how does Cucumber and Backbone work so I can't think of any *relevant* query.

Good luck!